# Caption above picture when using captionbox

Tags: floats

Im using captionbox for generating caption under the picture. I do it this way because I want to align caption with the side of picture even when I reduce size of the picture.

But I dont know how to get the caption above the picture. Still I need the caption align with the side of picture even when I reduce size of the picture.

```
\documentclass[%
12pt,     
a4paper,         
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}                                                                 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}            
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\captionsetup{
   font=footnotesize,
   justification=raggedright,
   singlelinecheck=false
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\color{FigureColor}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{1.5pt}  
\captionbox{Graf zobrazující hodnoty tvrdosti pro jednotlivé vzorky testovací sady 1 \label{TD01-tvrdost} }{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Obrazky/TD01-tvrdost.png}}
    \vspace{4pt}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks :-)

[image: problem with table caption]

Comment: Not related to the problem: you include two unwanted spaces in your `\captionbox` with the `\label{TD01-tvrdost}` command, one before it and one after it. Also your `figure` shows a table. Are you sure you don't want to use `table` instead?

Comment: It is only illustrative picture. So I want to use figure.

Answer (score 1):

Add the option `figureposition=top` to the list of options to `captionsetup`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}                                                                
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}            
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{
   font=footnotesize,
   justification=raggedright,
   singlelinecheck=false,
   figureposition=top % <=======    
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
%\color{FigureColor}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{1.5pt}  
\captionbox{Graf zobrazující hodnoty tvrdosti pro jednotlivé vzorky testovací sady 1 \label{TD01-tvrdost} }{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \vspace{4pt}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works but I have also a figures in document where I want a caption below. These settings set caption above for all figures.